# Highchart dual axis line and column chart with drill down dynamic percentage issue

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

We have been working on one client requirement where most of the graphs are Combination of line and column chart. We need drop down of minimum two level in each graph and sometimes it goes to three or four level. Now of value axis that is left side we displayed number value of column and on opposite right side we need to show percentage (%) of that value in the form of line. The issue is on the right side of value axis value remain same as of left axis instead of 1 to 100% in percentage if left side is A,B,C,D on right it shows again like A%,B%,C%,D% instead of 1to 100% and whenever we dig into bar graph the line doesn't appear on graph just column with percentage. We want to change it dynamically.  We are implementing it in PHP in YII2.
We are passing value of percentage like following:

```
$('#customchart').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    style: {
            fontFamily: 'Inter'
        }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'country',
    align: 'left',
    margin: 20,
    x:15,
    style: {
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: '16px',
        
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      marker: {
                fillColor: '#211F1F',
               // lineWidth: ,
                lineColor: null // inherit from series
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          var pcnt = (this.y / this.series.data.map(p => p.y).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) * 100;
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) + '%';
        }
      }
      
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: '400'
                
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'arriving',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: '600',
                color: '#211F1F'
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: '% arriving',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: '600',
                color: '#211F1F'
            }
        },
        labels: {
          style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: '400'
                
            },
          formatter:function() {
            // var pcnt = (this.value / this.series.data.map(p => p.y).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) * 100;
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0, ',') + '%';
          }
        },
        linkedTo: 0,
        opposite: true
    }],

  series: [{
    name: 'No. of Patients',
    colorByPoint: false,
    color:'#F7A4A4',
    data: <?php echo $countryJson?>,
    type: 'column',
     yAxis: 1
    
  },
  {
   name: '% of Patients',
   colorByPoint: false,
   color:'#A82828',
   data: <?php echo $countryJson?>,
   type: 'spline'
 }],
  drilldown: {
    series: <?=$countrystateArrJson ?>
  }
})
```

Attached is screenshot for same.
[image]

Comment: no one knows what you are doing OR what is wrong with it, untill unless you provide your complete code, you have just pasted the code for formatter only which is js , we need complete code how you are initializing the charts

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your requirements. Could please clarify and provide the full chart config?

Comment: @magdalena please see the code I have updated it.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Please, see the code.

Comment: @manpreet You used a highcharts tag but your config points to ApexCharts. Please, use the relevant tags in your questions.

Comment: @magdalena my bad.. i am working on multiple charts i just corrected it.

Comment: @manpreet thank you for the update. I added the answer, but still, I'm a bit lost in your requirements. Let me know if this is what you are looking for or if something needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the left axis is related to columns, the `series.yAxis` should be 0, and 1 for the `spline` series.

Secondly, the `yAxis.linkedTo` option duplicates the scales, which as I understand is not expected. I set min=0 and max= 100 for the right axis to simulate the percentage scale.

When it comes to the line data, you edit them only in the `dataLabels.formatter()`, which means, they are really the same, but only the labels change. If you want to count your data and show them as they are on the scale it has to be done i.e. in the chart `load()` event.

I simplified your config to make it more understandable.

**Check the following demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5c4367wg/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load